# Put two pandas dataframes together

Tags: python, pandas

Here are the two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['v0', 'v1', 'v0'], 'col2': ['v0', 'v1', 'v0'], 'col3': [10, 11, 12]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['v0', 'v1', 'v2', 'v0'], 'col2': ['v0', 'v1', 'v2', 'v0']})
```

And you can see that the values in each columns are NOT unique.

I would like to merge them together, but `merge` doesn't seem to do what I would like to achieve:

```
df2.merge(df1, how='left')
```

would return:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   v0        v0    10.0
1   v0        v0    12.0
2   v1        v1    11.0
3   v2        v2    NaN
4   v0        v0    10.0
5   v0        v0    12.0
```

I don't want them repetitions. I know I can drop duplicates, but in my original case it doesn't seem to do the job either.

I also tried `join`, but here is the result:

```
df2.join(df1, lsuffix='_caller', rsuffix='_other')
```

You can see that 'v0' from the `_caller` on the last row is not matched with 'v0' from `_other`, instead 'v2' is mathched with 'v0':

```
    col1_caller col2_caller col1_other  col2_other  col3
0   v0          v0          v0          v0          10.0
1   v1          v1          v1          v1          11.0
2   v2          v2          v0          v0          12.0
3   v0          v0          NaN         NaN         NaN
```

So I've been wandering is there a way how to merge them together and get the following result:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   v0        v0     10.0
1   v1        v1     11.0
2   v2        v2     NaN
3   v0        v0     12.0
```

**EDIT**

Actually, when I try the merge on my original dataframes I get the following error:

> Data columns not unique: Index[(...)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter columns in both `DatFrames` with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) and left join:

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby(['col1','col2']).cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby(['col1','col2']).cumcount()

df = df2.merge(df1, on=['col1','col2', 'g'], how='left').drop('g', axis=1)
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3
0   v0   v0  10.0
1   v1   v1  11.0
2   v2   v2   NaN
3   v0   v0  12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't *outer* merge do the job?

```py
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer').drop_duplicates()
```

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   v0      v0      10.0
2   v0      v0      12.0
4   v1      v1      11.0
5   v2      v2      NaN
```